# I can't find the process sending mail?

Tags: awk, ps, sendmail

I did something stupid and ran an awk that runs a while loop that sends an email every 10 seconds. I ran this as a background process:

```
egrep '^[1-9]' /etc/hosts | grep -v 'localhost' | awk '{ system("ssh "$1" \42\while (true); do uptime > /home/dan/test.txt; grep \x60\hostname\x60 /etc/hosts >> /home/dan/test.txt; echo >> /home/dan/test.txt; echo >> /home/dan/test.txt; /home/dan/myscript.pl | grep FAIL -A1 >> /home/dan/test.txt;echo >>/home/dan/test.txt; if [[ $(grep FAIL /home/dan/test.txt) != \x22\x22 ]]; then  sendmail jddancks@domain.net < /home/dan/test.txt; fi;sleep 10; done\42 &"); print "" }'
```

I realized I did something wrong, as a bunch of email are coming in, but I thought I could simply stop it if I simply close the shell. That didn't work. I tried doing other awks that run ps-efw and grep for keywords in that command, in case in might be running and then running a kill -9 on it. Nothing show ups. I checked `while`,`dan`,`sendmail`,`myscript.pl`:

```
egrep '^[1-9]' /etc/hosts | grep -v 'localhost' |  awk '{ system("ssh "$1" \42 ps -efw | grep sendmail\42");}'
```

I think my next bet is to check for processes sending mail on these boxes, and then killing or blocking it. I'm not sure how I can do this since nothing in ps aux shows up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scripts will most often be doing 'sleep 10'. Start by putting them into the stopped state:

```
pkill -ef --signal STOP 'sleep 10'
```

This will block the while loop. The use `ps -ef` or similar to find the parent id of the sleep (PPID column) and kill that process and the sleep. The parent process will be your shell, eg `bash`, which is implementing the `while` command which you cannot find.

You can kill the parent with a hangup signal after finding its parent using `ps` on the process id found by `pgrep`:

```
kill -hup $(ps -h -o ppid $(pgrep -f 'sleep 10'))
```

Comment: on an alternate way, you can use `ps -H` to locate `sleep 10` process, then manually (and quickly) kill parent and grand parent process.

Comment: @Archemar  He would need to do `ps -H` in the same terminal session, which I don't think he can, but you are right, something like `ps fa` will list a nice hierarchy showing what the parent of the sleep is. I was imagining he might want to write a script to get the PPID and do the kill, depending on how many remote machines he is running this on!

Comment: there are also `ps -H -f pts/XX` or `ps -H -u $LOGNAME` which will do nicely.

Comment: Well, I finally figured it out, these commands were very helpful. For some reason I had better luck grepping for other keywords in the script. So what happened was, the reason it was firing emails is because I got the quoting wrong and the command had `[[ != ]]` as its if statement lol. But also that 1) the script in its entirety was a process. It wasn't broken off or forked, threaded,etc 2) using & in the awk system() command plus the command passed to SSH made the script a child of init.d, like it was forked So I killed the awk shell but not the forked ssh processes. interesting

Comment: like a daemon process.